# 94 head gasket replacement now my car wont start

Tags: battery, alternator, accord, fuse, head-gasket

I replaced my head gasket and once I got to putting everything back together my car wouldnt start it wont crank and I have no power going to my car and suggestions

Comment: check the wiring, all the way from the battery terminals to the starter and control circuits.

Comment: About the only thing you should reasonably have disturbed electrically, that would prevent cranking, when doing this work is disconnecting the battery?

Comment: Solar mike/ could the starter still be the problem even know I didnt work on that part

Comment: Caius jard/ so I tried jump starting the battery I checked the connections all is good and the battery got checked as well and thats good so the battery has power